# mp4 from Android phone won't play as html video

Tags: android, html, video

I'm trying to play a video taken with an Android phone.  I want it to play in Chrome on a desktop or laptop.  When I run the code, I get the video controls.  When I play the video, I can hear the sound, but the video part is just empty background. I can get other videos to play just fine, but not the video from my phone.  In the code below, the duration reports correctly (1.8 sec), but the height and width are reported as zero.  (The test video from Big Buck Bunny plays just fine.)

What am I missing? (Yes, not a professional programmer, just a HS physics teacher...)

```html
<html> 
    <body> 
    <video width="400" controls id="theVideo">
        <source src="https://noragulfa.com/random/movie3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://distribution.bbb3d.renderfarming.net/video/mp4/bbb_sunflower_1080p_30fps_normal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </body>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("theVideo").addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(e) {
        console.log(this.videoWidth, this.videoHeight, this.duration);
    });
    </script>   
</html>
```

Comment: What type of video file. Which fike extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video (movie3.mp4) contains a HEVC/H.265 (1920x1080@30fps) video stream.

[Most browsers currently do not support HEVC/H.265](https://caniuse.com/?search=hevc). At the time of writing, only Safari does have support. Edge can also play HEVC/H.265 if the device has hardware decoding.

Please consider using [AVC/H.264](https://caniuse.com/?search=AVC), [VP8 or VP9](https://caniuse.com/?search=VP8) instead. For future reference, [AV1](https://caniuse.com/?search=AV1) would also make a great alternative but support is currently not that great yet.

Comment: OK.  Kind of a "doh!" moment.  I had no idea my phone was using HEVC/H.265  But I have changed it in settings and now it works fine.  I will just have to make sure my students do the same (on their iPhones, because that is what they ALL have).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine and working, The problem is with the video source that you are using, as you can see in the below code, I just replace your video URL with another URL and it working fine. the best solution would be to change your video source.

```html
<html> 
    <body> 
    <video width="400" controls id="theVideo">
        <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </body>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("theVideo").addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(e) {
        console.log(this.videoWidth, this.videoHeight, this.duration);
    });
    </script>   
</html>
```

You can you any free sites to host your video if you want, and use that URL to your code or maybe try to find another Url of the same video online.